# Copying F-Curves & Keyframes, but not adding to any action

Tags: python, animation, scripting, fcurves

I would like to copy an F-Curve, manipulate it, and add it back later. Is there a way to copy an F-Curve but not add it to any Action right away? I've tried using slice notation, but this still affects the F-Curve.

```py
for action in bpy.data.actions:
    for fcurve in action.fcurves[:]:
        new_keys = fcurve.keyframe_points[:]
        new_keys[0].co[0] = 3
```

I have also tried `deepcopy(fcurve)` but get the error: `cannot pickle 'FCurve' object`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the keyframe `co`s into a list with [`foreach_get`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection.html?highlight=foreach_get#bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection.foreach_get)

```
# Preallocate list of the right size
keys = [0] * (2 * len(fcurve.keyframe_points))
# Fill list from keyframe_points
fcurve.keyframe_points.foreach_get("co", keys)
```

The list is ordered like

```
keys = [kp[0].co[0], kp[0].co[1], kp[1].co[0], kp[1].co[1], ...]
```

To load it back in later, if you didn't change the size...

```
fcurve.keyframe_points.foreach_set("co", keys)
```

If you *did* change the size, you'll need to resize `keyframe_points` with [`add`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FCurveKeyframePoints.html#bpy.types.FCurveKeyframePoints.add) or [`remove`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FCurveKeyframePoints.html#bpy.types.FCurveKeyframePoints.remove) before `foreach_set`-ing it.

You can also fetch it into an `array.array` or numpy array instead of an ordinary list.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply! This is a good suggestion. For my needs, I have to copy everything from the FCurves (`data_path`,`array_index`, etc.) and Keyframes (`interpolation`, `type`, etc.). `foreeach_get` only works with bool, int and float datatypes. Do you know of a good way to copy all of the FCurve's (and its keyframes') data? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know a better way than just copying over all fields.